# How to click an element without id inside div without class using Xpath and C#

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium, xpath

[image]

I am supposed to click the link (highlighted blue, refer to image above), but `LinkText` does not work. I also tried using `CSSSelector` and `XPath`, but both:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CSSSelector("HH3"]")).Click();
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("div[text()="HH3"]")).Click();
```

doesn't work. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tried locator looks incorrect, you should try using `xpath` with text to locate desire element as below :-

```
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[text()='HH3']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text()='HH3')]")).Click();`

Comment: Code only answers are not good answers, try adding a few lines explaining what the problem was and how your code fixes it

Comment: Noted. Will take care next time.